# How to return exit of another bash script or perl script to another bash script

Tags: bash

I am calling a run.sh script inside sample.sh script and need to obtain the status of the run.sh in sample.sh. I would like to know how this can be done.

sample.sh

```
for var in ${testcases[@]}
do
  cd $unitdir
  run.sh
  echo " status $_ "
  if [[ $_ != 0 ]] ; then
    echo "******Test failed"
  else
    echo "******Test passed"
  fi
done;
```

The run.sh script is as follows. There is 0 being returning if the test script passes and a non-zero exit if it fails.

```
res=`diff $silverout $goldout`

if [ "${res}" != "" ] ; then
  exit 131
else
  exit 0
fi
```

However when I print the status of run.sh, it is status. Could you please let me know how to capture the status of the run.sh?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `$?` you need, not `$_`. Replace `$_` in your script with `$?`.

Also, I think echo is a normal command that has an exit status of its own, so you should comment out or delete that echo once it's working.

Comment: Thank you. I made the change, however, even when the exit is 131, Test passed is reported